# jQuery's serialize() function only returns the last selected checkbox value and not all of them!

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('form').serialize();

<label>Check what applies:</label>
Laptop Owner: <input type="checkbox" name="applicable" value="laptop owner" /> <br />
Samsung Tv Lover: <input type="checkbox" name="applicable" value="Samsumg tv lover" /> <br />
Animae Watcher: <input type="checkbox" name="applicable" value="Animae watcher" />
```

If I check "Laptop Owner" and "Animae Watcher" is only returns the latter, why? I need it to return both.

### EDIT

I should say when I send the forms values to PHP it only returns the last checked checkbox, this is what my php looks like:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['applicable'].' says PHP';

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `name="applicable"` to `name="applicable[]"`

```
<?php
print_r( $_POST['applicable'] );
?>
```

Comment: Little correction on your idea...Making applicable on client side will not make it array in server side. Here input will come as: applicable=val1&applicable=val2 ........So the merged string which came as input via serialized must be split and checked for applicable variable name to check multiple entry.

Comment: @seoul : doesn't possible ! in server side, cannot get value

Answer (score 1):

When `$('form').serialize()` is called it finds every input-textarea-select element inside the form tag and merge them with their name...

I am not sure how you have called .serialize() function so can't say anything because I have tested your code in my pc placing it inside a form element and it just work fine.

You better check JQuery documentation on this function: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: yeah it wasn't jQuery but that I neglected to mention "applicable" values would be an array in PHP